# Run a .go file under Apache from source by 'compiling on the fly'

Tags: apache, go

I'm able to run a Go application as a website with Apache using the following code.

**hello.go**:

```
package main

import (
    "os"
)

func main() {
    os.Stdout.WriteString("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\n\n")
    os.Stdout.WriteString("Hello!\n")
}
```

**.htaccess**:

```
AddHandler cgi-script .exe
```

I compile the app using `go build hello.go` and going to `http://localhost/hello.exe` works as expected.

But now I have to recompile after every change I make in the sourcecode.

Is it somehow possible to tell Apache to run `hello.go` (Apache should run `go run hello.go`) when visiting `http://localhost/hello.go`?

*By the way, this is only to speed development, not for production!*

Comment: how about a batch file that calls `go run` and you use that for `AddHandler`?

Comment: @dskinner: This doesn't work: Apache executes the batch file but no output is sent to the browser

Comment: Please do not use 'go run' anywhere in production. IMHO it is intended mostly as a convenience for throwaway experiments and/or similar activities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy solution would be to use a tool which re-compiles your code on changes to the source files. For example [`GoWatch`](https://bitbucket.org/gotamer/gowatch).

Or try it yourself by using `fsnotify` as Erik already stated. Example: [Simple Compile Daemon](https://github.com/githubnemo/CompileDaemon).

You could also invoke `go run` in your CGI script.

Comment: CompileDaemon (using fsnotify) did it for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Go is a compiled language, you'd need to compile it first. There currently aren't any interpreters/VM's for Go.

You're best bet is to just have a process/cron job that checks for the .go file being newer than the binary, and rebuilding it when it notices the file changed.

https://github.com/howeyc/fsnotify is a package that allows you to watch files for changes.

Comment: Go has excellent cross-compilation support. I would suggest building the binary locally, and uploading it to your servers.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [gorun](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/gorun) which enables you to put a `#!/usr/bin/gorun` line at the top of the file so it is run like a script.  gorun will compile it on the fly then run it.  I've used it quite a bit for making golang scripts and I expect it would work for CGIs too.

You'd have to mark the script as executable (`chmod +x`) and tell apache that the `.go` extension was executable.

Not sure I'd recommend this for production but it should work reasonably efficiently as `gorun` has a cache.